# How can I see in source code what facebook counts when they list the number of story viewers to my story?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web-applications

I would like to use source code to find a way to see who is looking at my stories and is not a friend of mine. Unfortunately I am not an expert of web apps and need help.

When I see the number of viewers I imagine something is being counted and would like to find what it is.

Thanks

Comment: That’s being counted on the server side. You have no access to the info which individual users viewed your stories.

Comment: You have apps for this kind of usages or maybe trying to use facebook for developers. anywat it is not mush of stackoverflow related question.

Comment: @noygafni Can you make an example of an app?